# JSF no navigation case matched

Tags: jsf, navigation

I want to navigate from a webpage to another with a Navigation Rule and get the facesmessage :

```
No navigation case match for viewId /content/diagram.xhtml,  action null and outcome edit_weekedit
```

My Faces Config looks like:

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/content/diagram.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>edit-weekedit</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/edit/editnotice.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

My method that navigates is:

```
public void changeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        SelectOneMenu source = (SelectOneMenu) event.getSource();
        if (source.getValue().equals("number_of_node")) {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String outcome = "edit_weekedit"; // Do your thing?
            facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext,null, outcome);
        }
    }
```

I use apache myfaces 2.0.

Whats wrong here?

Best Regards Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `changeListener` your outcome is `edit_weekedit` with **underscore** but in your config you have `edit-weekedit` with **hyphen**. Hence the error, please make both of them same and rerun.